# Problems with extended models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am currently working on a webapp for user authentication. The user should edit his attributes but when I try to extend the user model, it can not display the attributes.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Here my forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
        )

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
          'title',
     )
```

)

And this is the template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
```

The profile:form.as_p does not do anything and when I try to save the changes it also does not do anything. Clearly I am missing something, but I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass two separate dictionaries to `render`. You need one dictionary with two elements:

```
args = {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```